# Silverlight MapLayer right click issue

Tags: silverlight

I am currently developing a Silverlight OOB application using the Bing Map Control, however I have come across an issue I am struggling to resolve.  Basically I have three map layers:-

1. Base Map (bottom layer)
2. Icon / Pushpin layer (middle layer)
3. Shape / drawing layer (top layer)

This all works fine, I have put mouse right click functionality on each of my icons (pushpins if you prefer),  if I add a map polygon or polyline to the top layer and this item happens to cover the same area as one of my icons in the middle layer I can no longer get any of the mouse events to fire on my icon.

If anyone can think of a way I can pass the mouse operations from my top layer objects to the middle layer objects please let me know.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `IsHitTestVisible` of your top layer to `false`.  I feel I need to type more text here but there really isn't much more to say.

Comment: Both answers are very helpful, for the moment I am going to swap the layers order, if i get to a situation with other items that need to pass the mouse events around i will use a combination of the IsHitTestVisible property and some events between objects to control what happens.  Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question if you need both the shape and the icon to get the mouse event.

If all you need is for the icon to get the event, then switch the order of your layers so Icon layer is on top.

If you need both shape and icon to get the event, then (if you keep your order with shapes on top) you would need to have some way to tell what icons a shape covers.  Do you have a parent/child releationship between them?  If not, can you create one?  If you set up an event on the shape, and set up OnEvent handlers for the icons that listen to the events, then you can have the icons react as well.

If you are more clear about what your situation is, I could post some code that could help.